# change background color highlight for errors detected by pylint with ropevim and ropemode installed

Tags: python, vim, pylint

It changes the background to red, I can't read the text to correct the error!

How can I configure a different highlight? Does it have a setting?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I e-mailed the author directly and he gave me a helpful response. The highlight pyflakes uses for errors is SpellBad. He also gave me a couple of examples which I will share:

```
highlight SpellBad term=reverse ctermbg=1
```

Or for gvim users:

```
if has("gui_running")
    highlight SpellBad term=underline gui=undercurl guisp=Orange
endif
```

Answer (score 7):

I got an red background problem when a begin a string in python with " or '. After configure the spellbad options it seems like good.

```
highlight clear SpellBad
highlight SpellBad term=standout ctermfg=1 term=underline cterm=underline
highlight clear SpellCap
highlight SpellCap term=underline cterm=underline
highlight clear SpellRare
highlight SpellRare term=underline cterm=underline
highlight clear SpellLocal
highlight SpellLocal term=underline cterm=underline
```

Check For Details: http://hacktux.com/vim

Answer (score 4):

To see all the options for highlighting, open vim, go to normal mode and type

```
:highlight
```

to see all the modes.

e.g.

```
:highlight                                                                                                                                                                       
SpecialKey     xxx term=bold ctermfg=81 guifg=Cyan
NonText        xxx term=bold ctermfg=12 gui=bold guifg=Blue
Directory      xxx term=bold ctermfg=159 guifg=Cyan
ErrorMsg       xxx term=standout ctermfg=15 ctermbg=1 guifg=White guibg=Red
IncSearch      xxx term=reverse cterm=reverse gui=reverse
Search         xxx term=reverse cterm=underline gui=underline guifg=none guibg=none
MoreMsg        xxx term=bold ctermfg=121 gui=bold guifg=SeaGreen
ModeMsg        xxx term=bold cterm=bold gui=bold
LineNr         xxx term=underline ctermfg=11 guifg=Yellow
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked in the file of your colorscheme? You can look for these lines in your colorscheme file and change `guibg=COLOR` or  `ctermbg=COLOR` where you see

```
hi Error        guibg=Firebrick2 guifg=White
hi ErrorMsg     guibg=Firebrick2 guifg=White
```

Comment: It's not 'Error' & 'ErrorMsg', it's 'SpellBad' and something else for grammar errors. 'GrammarBad'?

Answer (score 0):

Now, ale exists, it's a higher level software to prevent errors from many sources.

https://github.com/w0rp/ale

> ALE (Asynchronous Lint Engine) is a plugin for providing linting in NeoVim and Vim 8 while you edit your text files.